# How to breakdown data by month and showing zero for months with no data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Using information in Table A, how can I produce results in Table B below?

Table A:

```
CASE_ID     DATE_EFF      COPAY   STATUS
      1     11/04/2016    10      A
      1     11/20/2016    5       A
      1     11/23/2016    5       R
      1     12/01/2016    1       A
      1     12/10/2016    2       A
      1     12/12/2016    10      A
      1     12/31/2016    50      R
```

For the above CASE_ID, we have dates in Nov 2016 and Dec 2016 only, however, I want to produce a breakdown of this CASE_ID for a period of 6 months as below where for each month the copays are summed where applicable as per the DATE_EFF and for the months that are not within the above dates, a zero is entered. Also, only records with copays with a status of 'A' are summed for any month -- so those with status of 'R' are ignored in the summation. For example, based on data in Table A above, the intended results are as follow:

Table B:

```
CASE_ID  MONTH     TOTAL_COPAY
1        01/2017   0
1        12/2016   13
1        11/2016   15
1        10/2016   0
1        09/2016   0
1        08/2016   0
```

I have below as a possible solution[using a with clause], **but can this be achieved without the use of the 'with' clause?**

Possible Solution:

```
WITH
XRF AS
( SELECT CASE_ID, COPAY, DATE_EFF
    FROM Table_A WHERE STATUS = 'A'
)
SELECT F.CASE_ID, ST, NVL(SUM(F.COPAY),0) TOTAL_COPAY FROM XRF F PARTITION BY (F.CASE_ID)
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT '12/2016' ST FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT '11/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '10/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '09/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '08/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '07/2016' FROM DUAL) STS
                                                  ON (TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY((F.DATE_EFF)),'MM/YYYY') = STS.ST)
GROUP BY F.CASE_ID, ST ORDER BY F.CASE_ID, ST DESC
;
```

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**
Using the above query, I believe I am have answered my own question by implementing it as below -- not sure though if using this method is expensive when you have millions of records of such CASE_IDs. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT F.CASE_ID, ST, NVL(SUM(F.COPAY),0) TOTAL_COPAY FROM (SELECT CASE_ID, COPAY, DATE_EFF FROM TABLE_A WHERE STATUS = 'A') F PARTITION BY (F.CASE_ID)
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT '12/2016' ST FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT '11/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '10/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '09/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '08/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT '07/2016' FROM DUAL) STS
                                                  ON (TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY((F.DATE_EFF)),'MM/YYYY') = STS.ST)
GROUP BY F.CASE_ID, ST ORDER BY F.CASE_ID, ST DESC
;
```

Comment: Search for `PARTITIONED OUTER JOIN`

Comment: How did you decide the table will go up to January 2017 (and not December 2016, or February 2017)? Or is that a user input?

Comment: @mathguy it is a user input, more like a restriction, so hardcoded. in this particular case, i am interested in august '16 to january '17.

Comment: @MTO thanks for the suggestion. Looking up on implementing using this.

Comment: Any assistance in a solution of the above without using 'with' clause? I'd like if at all possible to have it as one code.

Comment: @DaveJabbz. What is the issue with the "with" clause?

Comment: @BobC i needed a "simpler" version which would enable me to join many other tables which require their own sets of conditions -- for these other tables, they'd have their own code blocks[i.e. TABLE_A AS(...), TABLE_B AS(...)] within the 'with' clause. So with the example of the query that I have above under my 'UPDATE', i can put it among the other blocks within the 'with' clause as-is and join this to the base table which i have in the main select statement. I hope this makes sense. As-is though, I am not entirely sure whether the above solution is expensive when you have millions of records.